# FFMPEG Incorrect frame size, How to resolve?

Tags: ffmpeg, centos

running on CentOS 5.6, is it possible to fix this issues ?

```
[ragopor@xs1 livestream]$ ffmpeg -i hello.mp4 -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 64k -s 320×240 -vcodec libx264 -b 96k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 5 -trellis 1 -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 96k -bufsize 96k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 320:240 -g 30 -async 2 helloout.mp4
FFmpeg version 0.6.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec  4 2010 15:35:31 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0

Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 59.83 (29917/500) -> 29.92 (29917/1000)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'hello.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42
  Duration: 00:02:47.66, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 644 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 102 kb/s
    Stream #0.1(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 480x320 [PAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 539 kb/s, 29.92 fps, 29.92 tbr, 29917 tbn, 59.83 tbc
Incorrect frame size
[ragopor@xs1 livestream]$
```

Comment: That's a lot of fine-tuning you're doing!  Do you have the same problem if you just do something simple like `ffmpeg -i hello.mp4 -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264`?

Answer (score 3):

I think the `-s 320×240` should be placed before `-acodec`? Kind of `ffmpeg -i hello.mp4 -s 320x240 -f mpegts -acodec ..`